# How to filter value in Big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have Table1 :

ID Name Tag  Date

1. abc  good 2/01/2022
2. bcd  good 2/01/2022
3. def  bad  2/02/2022
4. abc  bad  2/02/2022
5. bcd  bad  2/02/2022
6. abc  good 2/03/2022
7. abc  bad  2/04/2022

Result :

id Name Tag Date

1. abc  good 2/01/2022
2. bcd  good 2/01/2022
3. def  bad  2/02/2022

I am trying to get the Tag detail for particular name based on min date.
How to filter out the data because when i am doing big query i have to add Tag in group it goes back square one. can you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select as value array_agg(t order by date limit 1)[offset(0)]
from  your_table t
group by name
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]